# Subrule to compare two times with format (XX:XX) in Prolog

Tags: time, prolog, comparison

I'm trying to compare two times to see which time is less than the other. An example implementation would be ArrivalTime < DepartureTime2, where both ArrivalTime and DepartureTime2 could take on a value of format (XX:XX) such as 12:00 or 15:50. I was thinking about converting the XX:XX format into a regular XXXX format, but I do not know how to do so. Is there any other way to go about this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is usually expected that you show at least some effort: code you have tried, and how it hasn't worked. For example, did you try to write `?- 12:00 < 15:00.` and what happened when you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need. A time written as `12:00` or `15:50` is a valid Prolog term. You can compare them using term comparison (instead of arithmetic comparison):

```
?- 12:00 @< 15:50.
true.

?- 12:00 @< 5:50.
false.
```

You should read the documentation of the Prolog you are using. In SWI-Prolog, for example, the relevant section is ["Standard order of terms"](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder).

By the way, if you are wondering how Prolog sees a term as `15:50`:

```
?- write_canonical(15:50).
:(15,50)
true.
```

This tells you that `15:50` is interpreted as a term with functor `:/2`, with the hours as the first argument and the minutes as the second. This works because `:` is declared as an operator:

```
?- current_op(Precedence, Type, :).
Precedence = 600,
Type = xfy.
```

You could have just as well used a representation as `h_m(15, 50)`. Such terms will sort identically:

```
?- h_m(12, 00) @< h_m(15, 50).
true.
```